# Oracle SQL to format field

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

I'm looking for a Oracle sql to format a payment condition field to a specific format as below:

```
Original
30/60/90/120/150/180
Formated
30 60 90 120150180

Original
150/180/210
Formated
150180210
```

The only thing I came up with is 
`replace(pgto, '/', ' ')` and the result is `30 60 90 12 150 180`
I was thinking about regexp_replace but I'm not familiar with.

Edit: The original payment condition can have up to 12 positions separated by "/" and each position can have 1 to 3 digits.
[image: Example]

Comment: Why is the `/` replaced with a blank in first example, but not in the second?

Comment: because it has 3 digits, so it should replace with a blank the other positions if 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT value AS original,
       LTRIM(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           '^((\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/)?(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$',
           '\2 \3 \4 \5\6\7'
         )
       ) AS formatted
FROM   table_name;
```

So for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '30/60/90/120/150/180' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '150/180/210' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ORIGINAL             | FORMATTED         
> :------------------- | :-----------------
> 30/60/90/120/150/180 | 30 60 90 120150180
> 150/180/210          | 150180210
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dbf2e343935f51037c31920444e4b90a)*

---

**Updated**:

If I have understood your updated requirements correctly, you have 1-to-3 digit numbers in a slash delimited list and you want to output this list without the slashes and so that each number is right-padded with spaces so it always fills 3 characters.

You can find each 1-3 digit number and append two spaces to it and then find the non-slash characters and keep the first 3 in each group (discarding any additional ones and the trailing slash):

```sql
SELECT value AS original,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           '(\d{1,3})(/|$)',
           '\1  /'
         ),
         '([^/]{3})[^/]{0,2}/',
         '\1'
       ) AS formatted
FROM   table_name;
```

for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '30/60/90/120/150/180' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '150/180/210' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '90/120/150' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '30/60/90' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '30/60/90/120' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1/10/100/2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORIGINAL             | FORMATTED         
> :------------------- | :-----------------
> 30/60/90/120/150/180 | 30 60 90 120150180
> 150/180/210          | 150180210         
> 90/120/150           | 90 120150         
> 30/60/90             | 30 60 90          
> 30/60/90/120         | 30 60 90 120      
> 1/10/100/2           | 1  10 1002
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ca108a864c8feb0854c66c12e34a55b)*

Comment: Thank you @MT0 it almost work, but there is more conditions, should I list them all?

`CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '30/60/90/120/150/180' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '150/180/210' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '90/120/150' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '30/60/90' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '30/60/90/120' FROM DUAL;`

`ORIGINAL                    FORMATTED
30/60/90/120/150/180    30 60 90 120150180
150/180/210                    150180210
90/120/150                    90120150
30/60/90                            306090
30/60/90/120                    30/60/90/120`

Comment: @kelsen Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60075168/edit) your question rather than posting code/output into comments. I can work out what the code means but the lack of formatting the comment imposes on the output leaves it very confusing what point you are trying to make.

Comment: I'm sorry @MT0 I'm not used to post questions. I've edited the question with more specifications and a imagem as example.

Comment: @kelsen Updated. If that isn't what you want then you'll need to edit the question with a detailed specification of the problem so we can understand what you are trying to achieve.